# Join 3 tables and calculate values based on 2 key columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables that needs to be joined, 2 of them are important to calculate a value and provide it in the third one, the problem is in these 2 tables I have 2 columns that I need to grouped for the calculation.

These are the tables - first table:

```
SELECT customerId, baseCurrencyId, SUM(amount) AS totalRecovered
FROM dbo.RecoveredDebt
WHERE (isDeleted = 0)
GROUP BY customerId, baseCurrencyId;
```

Result of fist query:

| customerId | baseCurrencyId | totalRecovered |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 950 |
| 4 | 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 2 | 100 |
| 2 | 2 | 500 |

Second table:

```
SELECT customerId, baseCurrencyId, SUM(amount) AS totalOld
FROM dbo.OldDebt
WHERE (isDeleted = 0)
GROUP BY customerId, baseCurrencyId;
```

Result of second query:

| customerId | baseCurrencyId | totalOld |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 2000 |
| 1 | 2 | 100 |
| 2 | 2 | 300 |

And now here comes the trick, I want to select from `Customer` table and get these columns:

```
id (customer id), 
baseCurrencyId, 
totalOldDebt (from first query), 
totalRecoveredDebt (from second query), 
totalDebt (totalOldDebt - totalRecoveredDebt)
```

But I want it to be grouped by `baseCurrencyId`, for example if a customer has debts with more than one currency the calculation must be done for each of them, if there are rows in one table with a currency but not the other table then the values for that one must be zero and the calculation still happens.

Here is my expected result after the calculations based on the provided tables:

| id | baseCurrencyId | totalOldDebt | totalRecoveredDebt | totalDebt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 100 | 100 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 2000 | 950 | 1050 |
| 2 | 2 | 300 | 500 | -200 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 | 10 | -10 |

I have tried using CTE but I could not figure out how to do so:

```
WITH OldCTE AS 
(
    SELECT    
        customerId, baseCurrencyId, SUM(amount) AS totalOld
    FROM
        dbo.OldDebt
    WHERE     
        (isDeleted = 0)
    GROUP BY  
        customerId, baseCurrencyId
), 
RecoveredCTE AS 
(
    SELECT    
        customerId, baseCurrencyId, SUM(amount) AS totalRecovered
    FROM
        dbo.RecoveredDebt
    WHERE     
        (isDeleted = 0)
    GROUP BY  
        customerId, baseCurrencyId
)
SELECT C.id
FROM Customer AS C
LEFT JOIN OldCTE AS OCTE ON OCTE.customerId = C.id
LEFT JOIN RecoveredCTE AS RCTE ON RCTE.customerId = C.id
```

Comment: Since you SUM both tables, all you are missing is the calculation (`totalOldDebt - totalRecoveredDebt`) in the last `SELECT`.

Comment: @Eric it wont work because it will repeat the rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want use a CTE as a variant:

```
WITH OldCTE AS 
(
    SELECT customerId, baseCurrencyId, SUM(amount) AS totalOld
    FROM dbo.OldDebt
    WHERE (isDeleted = 0)
    GROUP BY customerId, baseCurrencyId
), 
RecoveredCTE AS 
(
    SELECT customerId, baseCurrencyId, SUM(amount) AS totalRecovered
    FROM dbo.RecoveredDebt
    WHERE (isDeleted = 0)
    GROUP BY customerId, baseCurrencyId
)
SELECT 
    C.id,
    COALESCE(OCTE.totalOld, 0) AS totalOldDebt,
    COALESCE(RCTE.totalRecovered, 0) AS totalRecoveredDebt,
    COALESCE(OCTE.totalOld, 0) - COALESCE(RCTE.totalRecovered, 0) AS totalDebt
FROM  
    OldCTE AS OCTE
FULL JOIN  
    RecoveredCTE AS RCTE ON RCTE.customerId = OCTE.customerId 
                         AND OCTE.baseCurrencyId = RCTE.baseCurrencyId
JOIN 
    Customer AS C ON C.id = COALESCE(OCTE.customerId, RCTE.customerId)
```

PS: I'm not very familiar with SQL Server, but you probably can write it without CTE:

```
SELECT
    C.id,
    COALESCE(OD.baseCurrencyId, RD.baseCurrencyId) AS currency,
    COALESCE(SUM(OD.amount), 0) AS totalOldDebt,
    COALESCE(SUM(RD.amount), 0) AS totalRecoveredDebt,
    COALESCE(SUM(OD.amount), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(RD.amount), 0) AS totalDebt
FROM
    dbo.OldDebt AS OD
FULL JOIN
    dbo.RecoveredDebt AS RD ON OD.customerId = RD.customerId 
                            AND OD.baseCurrencyId = RD.baseCurrencyId 
                            AND RD.isDeleted = 0
JOIN
    Customer AS C ON C.id = COALESCE(OD.customerId, RD.customerId)
WHERE
    OD.customerId IS NULL OR OD.isDeleted = 0
GROUP BY
    C.id, COALESCE(OD.baseCurrencyId, RD.baseCurrencyId)
```

Also I'm not sure about this more optimal, for it need check query plan.

Comment: Thank you, do you know if it can be achived by Union between the queries?, this one you posted works as expeced i am just curious about it

Comment: Adding `coalesce(OCTE.baseCurrencyId, RCTE.baseCurrencyId) as baseCurrencyId` to the select list will yield the missing column - [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zSiHGgue).

Comment: the second one wont work because if there are more rows in either table the otherone's value will changes

Answer (score 0):

You need to first perform a `FULL OUTER JOIN` between the old debt and recovered debt, gather the values, and then join that with your customer. This can be done either in a subselect or another CTE.  (...Or, as Gwaeren posted in another answer ahead of mine, by just reordering the joins.)

```
WITH OldCTE AS (
    SELECT    customerId, baseCurrencyId, SUM(amount) AS totalOldDebt
    FROM      dbo.OldDebt
    WHERE     (isDeleted = 0)
    GROUP BY  customerId, baseCurrencyId
), RecoveredCTE AS (
    SELECT    customerId, baseCurrencyId, SUM(amount) AS totalRecoveredDebt
    FROM      dbo.RecoveredDebt
    WHERE     (isDeleted = 0)
    GROUP BY  customerId, baseCurrencyId
), MergedCTE AS (
    SELECT
        COALESCE(R.customerId, O.customerId) AS customerId,
        COALESCE(R.baseCurrencyId, O.baseCurrencyId) AS baseCurrencyId,
        ISNULL(O.totalOldDebt, 0) AS totalOldDebt,
        ISNULL(R.totalRecoveredDebt, 0) AS totalRecoveredDebt
    FROM OldCTE O
    FULL OUTER JOIN RecoveredCTE R
        ON R.customerId = O.customerId
        AND R.baseCurrencyId = O.baseCurrencyId
)
SELECT
    C.Id,
    M.baseCurrencyId,
    M.totalOldDebt,
    M.totalRecoveredDebt,
    M.totalOldDebt - M.totalRecoveredDebt AS totalDebt
FROM Customer AS C
JOIN MergedCTE M
    ON M.customerId = C.Id
ORDER BY
    C.id,
    M.baseCurrencyId
```

Results:

| Id | baseCurrencyId | totalOldDebt | totalRecoveredDebt | totalDebt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 100 | 100 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 2000 | 950 | 1050 |
| 2 | 2 | 300 | 500 | -200 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 | 10 | -10 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9IH1WU8K) for a demo.

**Addendum:** You asked on another comment, and yes, `UNION` is yet another approach:

```
WITH UnionCTE AS (
    SELECT
        customerId,
        baseCurrencyId,
        SUM(old) AS totalOldDebt,
        SUM(recovered) AS totalRecoveredDebt
    FROM (
        SELECT    customerId, baseCurrencyId, amount AS old, 0 as recovered
        FROM      dbo.OldDebt
        WHERE     (isDeleted = 0)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT    customerId, baseCurrencyId, 0 AS old, amount as recovered
        FROM      dbo.RecoveredDebt
        WHERE     (isDeleted = 0)
    ) U
    GROUP BY  customerId, baseCurrencyId
)
SELECT     C.id,
           UCTE.baseCurrencyId, UCTE.totalOldDebt, UCTE.totalRecoveredDebt,
           UCTE.totalOldDebt - UCTE.totalRecoveredDebt AS totalDebt
FROM       Customer AS C
JOIN       UnionCTE AS UCTE ON UCTE.customerId = C.id
ORDER BY   C.Id, UCTE.baseCurrencyId
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SP1oIEq3).

There are other methods. If your real-life query only needs to access a small subset of your customers (or perhaps just one at a time), it might make sense to calculate the debt using a `CROSS APPLY` that only accesses those debt rows associated with the selected customer(s).  Preselecting your customer IDs into a temp table (or table variable) and using that to pre-filter the debt data is also an option.

Comment: is there any value difference between your answer and this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78234078/11707666

Comment: Not really. I was preparing my answer independently and only saw the other answer just prior to posting.

Comment: is the union better or CTE?

Comment: I wouldn't expect a significant difference, but if performance is a issue, you can test both.